# jquery IE8 animate opacity png bad rendering

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I've got a problem with animate opacity in IE8. I have some png with shade starting with opacity 0 and animate to opacity 1. But when the browser render the images.. this happens:

[image: [image_1][1]<br]

and after half second the image render ok! ..

Comment: post ur code as fiddle  inorder to help u ...

Comment: the code is so easy!
$('.frame2').delay(300).animate({  width:80, height:78, opacity : 1 }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo' , function(){ ...

Comment: post the code i need to know wat u have tried and help accordingly..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/faXdm/1/

Comment: hi just worked on this using ie8 check this code infiddle still issues let me know..http://jsbin.com/OHaNENu/1/edit

Comment: still dont work! now the shadow remains black and never render good!

Comment: hi just replace this code of line 'filter:inherit' to css(filter line is there in css) which i have provided